# How to exempt a library module from pro-guard in android gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

Release version of my Android app crashes with the following exception

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/mm/android/dhproxy/client/DHProxyClient;.InitWithName(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I"`

This error is not found in debug version and hence is because of the proguard I guess.

The above mentioned class is in one of the modules which also use JNI libraries.
My **proguard-rules** for the **app module** file is below

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
-keep class com.mm.android.dhproxy.client.DHProxyClient
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
    void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

The build.gradle file for the concerned module is below

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/IPlaySDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/ToUProxy.jar')
}
```

even after adding the line `-keep class com.mm.android.dhproxy.client.DHProxyClient` I can see that the usage.txt file conatins the following entries

```
com.mm.android.dhproxy.client.DHProxyClient:
    29:35:public boolean initWithName(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    64:69:public int delPort(int)
    136:141:public int queryRate(int,com.mm.android.dhproxy.client.DHProxyRateParam)
    158:163:public int p2pSetOption(int,int)
    180:185:public int p2pGetOption(int)
    192:197:public int exit()
    private native int InitWithName(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    private native int DelPort(int,int)
    private native int P2PSetOption(int,int,int)
    private native int P2PGetOption(int,int)
    private native int QueryRate(int,com.mm.android.dhproxy.client.DHProxyRateParam,int)
    private native int Exit(int)
com.mm.android.dhproxy.client.DHProxyRateParam
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to look up for the methods and classess that needs to be exempted and add them to the proguard rules as follows ( Here I needed to keep the files in classes com.mm.** and com.company.** where ** acts as wild char

```
-keep class com.mm.** {*;}
-keep class com.company.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers  class com.mm.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers  class com.company.** {*;}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did not have the two asterisks and the submask in curly braces and it almost did what it needed to do. It only left out the constructors. Having just spent a couple of man-days searching for the cause of the crash :(

Answer (score 5):

If you are using external/separate source libraries with your main project/application, you should not use a proguard on the library modules. Instead, you replace the following,

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

with the following (in the build.gradle of the library/libraries):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```

where proguard-project.txt is the file that contains the proguard rules for your library project. When building the application (either in debug or release mode), the compiler will take care of all the rules (in the library and in the application).

Source: This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031491/3490458)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting minifyEnabled to true and generate the release build using the following command.

./gradlew assembleRelease if you are using mac
gradlew assembleRelease if you are using widows

Check the build after you ran the command and see if it works

Comment: Well I want the library to be exempted from the minify process

Comment: I think if you don't make you minifyenabled true your proguard will be ignored. Did you generate the release build using the commands i mentioned?

Comment: release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }